# Share a link text bug

Tags: bug, status-declined

[image: Screenshot of bug] There is a bug below [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1226323/excel-find-in-workbook-shortcut) where the share a link text does not appear correctly.

It is rendered as "Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, , , or ."

Comment: Turn off your ad blocker... what happens?

Comment: @Oded perfect, I didn't realise ad blockers even disabled text. I will disable it for SE sites